Markers are not fixed and are rendered outside map with react-map-gl
I am currently trying to build a simple map inside my web application that should display a fixed set of points on the map. For this example I am using the pre-defined coordinate points from cities.json.
Here is an example of how the entries look:
{"city":"New York","population":"8,175,133","image":"http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/Above_Gotham.jpg/240px-Above_Gotham.jpg","state":"New York","latitude":40.6643,"longitude":-73.9385},

I am facing two issues that I struggle to understand:

My markers are calculated and are visible outside the range of the
map (see picture one)
My markers seem to be dynamic, e.g. they move along the map when I zoom in and out, so they do not remain static on the map, regardless of my action.
Which is not really important (I can not see any the different control elements for the map - NavigationControl,FullscreenControl,ScaleControl,GeolocateControl).


I am a complete beginner, so I really appreciate any help from you guys!
Here is my code:
import * as React from 'react';
import {useState, useMemo} from 'react';
import {createRoot} from 'react-dom/client';
import Map, {
  Marker,
  Popup,
  NavigationControl,
  FullscreenControl,
  ScaleControl,
  GeolocateControl
} from 'react-map-gl';

import {
    MapPinIcon
  } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";

import CITIES from './cities.json';

const TOKEN = ''; // Set your mapbox token here

export default function TestMap() {

  const pins = useMemo(
    () =>
      CITIES.map((city, index) => (
        <Marker
          key={`marker-${index}`}
          longitude={city.longitude}
          latitude={city.latitude}
          anchor="bottom"
        >
          <MapPinIcon className="marker w-8 h-8"alt="Marker"></MapPinIcon>
        </Marker>
      )),
    []
  );

  return (
    <div style={{width: '100vw', height: '100vh'}}>
      <Map
        initialViewState={{
          latitude: 40,
          longitude: -100,
          zoom: 3.5,
          bearing: 0,
          pitch: 0
        }}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
        mapboxAccessToken={import.meta.env.VITE_MAPBOX_API_KEY}
      >
        <GeolocateControl position="top-left" />
        <FullscreenControl position="top-left" />
        <NavigationControl position="top-left" />
        <ScaleControl />

        {pins}
      </Map>
    </div>
  );
}


For everyone that stumbles upon the same problem: please look at this post: link, a combination of importing import 'mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css'; and changing to the pin used in the demo project instead of using my one did the trick! ;)
